# When to use “in the last year”, “last year” and “in the past year”?

Tags: differences, word-usage, adverbials

I'm curious about the differences between "in the last year", "in the past year" and "last year".

- I went to NY in the past year
- Last year I went to NY.
- In the last year I went to NY (This sounds wrong to me).

Could you please explain when to use each?

Comment: This likely belongs at http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: related: ['In' the past few years Vs 'Over' the past few years](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26317/in-the-past-few-years-vs-over-the-past-few-years)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the last year, last year, in the past year

How do such things come into being? We may assume that the beginnings were something like this: When was it? - That was in the last year. Then you may assume that this was shortened to: That was last year. The omission of self-evident "in" does not change the meaning.
Then "last year" alone can be used as an adverbial group in a sentence.
So "Last year we went to Italy" will be the most frequent formula, simply because it is the shortest indication of "when".
Of course you can use the longer formula "In the last year we went to Italy." There is no difference of meaning at all. It is only longer, and an author may use it simply for rhythmic and stylistic reasons. You may also use it in spoken language, for example when you need some time to formulate what you want to say. 
But we can say when there is a short formula then it is the short formula that is most frequently used.
In the past year: The idea is exactly the same. It is simply a different "picture".
When you say "the last year" you think of a row of things and you choose the thing at the end.
When you say "the past year" you think that an event has gone by or passed. 
If I would look at Google N-gram Viewer, I think, that "in the past year" is less common than "last year". I would say it is a variant that can be found occasionally.

Comment: I would say: *I've been to NY in the past year*, because the "year" is not finished.

Comment: Only two results for [*in the last year we went*](https://www.google.co.uk/#tbm=bks&q=%22In+the+last+year+we+went%22)

Answer (score 3):

In the phrase "*past year*", *year* denotes a period of 365 days before the time being mentioned; "*Last year*" refers to the previous calender year.

**Situation 1**:

- Today is Jan. 1 2015
- I went to NY on Jan. 1 2014.

Then I would say: "*I went to NY in the past year*".

**Situation 2**:

- Today is July. 20 2015
- I went to NY on Jan. 1 2014.

Then I would say: "*I went to NY last year*".

Comment: No! In Situation 1 you could use any of the three forms,'in the past year', 'in the last year', or 'last year'. In Situation 2 you could not use either of the first two, but you could say 'last year'.

Comment: True, but I was just trying to illustrate the use of 'past year'.